# Do not open page when try to make login using jquery, ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the file "index.html" that contains login form, a file "dash.js" that gets username and password from login form and redirects to the file "connectdb.php" that check the login with database, and in case of success start a session in file "stock.php". The problem is that when I try to make login it redirects to the file "stock.php", but it sends again for index.html, do not showing the page "stock.php". The password and username are correct. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is go my code.

dash.js

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function() {
    var username = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
    console.log("passsas qaqiioooo" + username + "- " + password);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'connectdb.php',
        data: {user: username, pass: password},
        success: function(data){
                window.location="stock.php";
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('deu barraca: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

connectdb.php

```
<?php

$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '********';
$database = '***********';

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database);

if (!$con) {
  die('Nao e possivel conectar a base de dados: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


if (isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
      $myusername = $_POST['user'];
    $mypassword = $_POST['pass'];
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
}
?>
```

stock.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset( $_SESSION['myusername'] )){
    header("location:index.html");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem i can see here is that your `$.ajax` `success` event is fired in every case. no matter if your database connection fails, your login-data is correct or incorrect. `$.ajax` will always be successful in getting a valid response from your `connectdb.php`.
there are different ways to make it work, here is my simple suggestion:

**1.** in your `connectdb.php`-file, make sure you are always returning something with `echo`:

```
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
    $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
    echo "success";
}
else 
{
    echo "login_failed";
}
```

**2.** in your `$.ajax` function check for the value returned:

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function() {
    var username = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#pass').val();
    console.log("passsas qaqiioooo" + username + "- " + password);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'connectdb.php',
        data: {user: username, pass: password},
        success: function(data){

            //debug the response:
            console.log(data);

            if(data == "success")
            {
                window.location="stock.php";
            }
            else if(data == "login_failed")
            {
                alert("login failed!");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("unknown response: " + data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('deu barraca: ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTE:** it would be even better to use `$.ajax` with `dataType: "json"`. but i assume you are quite new to `AJAX` in general, so i kept my solution rather simple.

**UPDATE** - found another issue: 
**3.** you don't start your `session` in `connectdb.php`, so your `session vars` are never saved to the `session`:

```
session_start(); // <-- start the session here
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '********';
$database = '***********';
/* 
... 
*/
```

Comment: I change my code, with your suggestions but still doesn't work. I put an `alert("Success")` in the first `if` and shows the message, but returns to the "index.html". If I remove this `if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'] )){ header("location:index.html");` in the file "stock.php" then shows the page with message "Login Successful". :S

Comment: what is the value of `data` in your browser's console? i added `console.log(data);` so you can see what message is returned by your php script.

Comment: The value returned is "success", so it´s correct. I assume that the problem can be the file "stock.php".

Comment: oh wait - i just found another issue. i'll update my answer in a sec.

Comment: updated it - this should be the last issue - fingers crossed :-)